# Android HttpResponse - working in Emulator but not working in Device

Tags: android, httpresponse

I am very new in Android programming. I am trying to connect and get response from a Link, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/

I have used `HttpResponse` to get the response and then used `EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity())` function to convert the response to a string. My code is running perfectly in Emulator but when I am trying to run the project in real Device i.e. Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.0, it does not run and says "Unfortunately, ... has stopped".

Can any one please let me know why this is happening and what is the solution around? The code is following:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String pageStr = "***";

        try
        {
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://stackoverflow.com/");

            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);

            if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                pageStr = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        txt.setText(pageStr);

    }
}
```

I have used the following permission in the `manifest` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Any help or suggestion regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It crashed.  List the full crash log here.

Comment: The following answer solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you are trying to access to internet in UI thread.

Read following link, it says [how to work with internet in separate (non UI) thread](http://www.android-ever.com/2012/10/android-asynctask-example.html).